# How to prompt a user to re-enter a number after an invalid entry

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I am having the user be prompted to enter a number which will be the maximum number that a random number will be in between. The code works if they enter a number when prompted the first time and the code picks a random number between 1 and the maximum number entered. If the user does not enter a number (i.e. enters a letter or symbol), I want the user to be prompted again to enter a number. I also need to add code to ensure the number entered is positive

```js
let num_guess = 0
let tries = []

let max_num = Number(prompt("Enter a maximum number:"));
if (isNaN(max_num)) {
  // need to reprompt user to enter a valid maximum number and make sure that the user will keep being prompted until a positive number is entered
}

let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_num) + 1;

console.log(max_num)
console.log(num)

function do_guess() {
  let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);

  let message = document.getElementById("message");

  if (tries.includes(guess)) {
    message.innerHTML = "That number has already been guessed, try again"
  } else if (isNaN(guess)) {
    message.innerHTML = 'That is not a number!';
  } else if (guess <= 0 || guess > max_num) {
    message.innerHTML = 'That number is not in range, try again.';
  } else if (guess > num) {
    message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
    num_guess++
    tries.push(guess)
  } else if (guess < num) {
    message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    num_guess++
    tries.push(guess)
  } else if (guess == num) {
    num_guess++
    tries.push(guess)
    message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + num_guess + " tries and your guesses were " + tries + ".";
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you just now delete [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68307987/) after it has been answered? That is not kind

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that calls for the input. If the input is invalid, you call the function again from inside itself.

```js
let num_guess = 0;
let tries = [];
let max_num = 0;

// Add this function to keep prompting user until a valid input is entered.
function getInput() {
  var inputValue = Number(prompt("Enter a maximum number:"));
  if (isNaN(inputValue)) {
    return getInput();
  }
  else {
    return inputValue;
  }
}

max_num = getInput();

let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_num) + 1;

console.log(max_num)
console.log(num)

function do_guess() {
  let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);

  let message = document.getElementById("message");

  if (tries.includes(guess)) {
    message.innerHTML = "That number has already been guessed, try again"
  } else if (isNaN(guess)) {
    message.innerHTML = 'That is not a number!';
  } else if (guess <= 0 || guess > max_num) {
    message.innerHTML = 'That number is not in range, try again.';
  } else if (guess > num) {
    message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
    num_guess++
    tries.push(guess)
  } else if (guess < num) {
    message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    num_guess++
    tries.push(guess)
  } else if (guess == num) {
    num_guess++
    tries.push(guess)
    message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + num_guess + " tries and your guesses were " + tries + ".";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I fixed in in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `prompt` in a  [`do ... while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)

```js
let max_num; 

do {
  max_num = Number(prompt("Enter a maximum number:"));
} while (isNaN(max_num))

let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_num) + 1;

console.log({max_num, num})
```

Comment: Good use of a do...while loop! Don’t see many of those.

Comment: @DanMullin It's typically when you need a while loop but you are sure you need it to run once.

Comment: I don’t use them often and forget it even exists sometimes.

Comment: I don't either, I must say that in 20+ years of development I have used it fewer than 10 times :D